# Retrieving data with angularfire2 and angular 4

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

My database is given 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAQ7D.png). I want to retrieve the total data tree of **Post** with the key under **Post**

I have tried with the code given below. but this provides me a list **with 0 1 2 3 instead of original key ( KxZPLJh9k4ldXqz3gNF ) under Post**

```
this.db.list('/post', ref => ref.orderByChild('course').equalTo("che101f")).valueChanges();
```

Is there any way to have my desired data tree ? If so how ?

Comment: db.list sends back an array, but you should still be able to access the key. I think it's under $key.

Comment: you need to use `snapshotChanges()` for it.

Comment: Check this example app [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#deleting-the-entire-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valueChanges()` strips the metadata, it's only intended for simple access to your JSON tree.

You should use `snapshotChanges()` if you want to access anything other than the JSON tree, such as pushIds.

[Check out the docs here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#snapshotchanges).